# What does the declaration '(int *) ptr[N]' mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

I found a puzzling array when I tried to put parenthesis to emphasize the declaration of array of pointers as in `(int *) ptr[N];`.

The GCC C compiler says:

`error: ptr undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Can anyone explain the origin of the error please?

Comment: Although unhelpful for your specific question those two references might come handy later on for similar questions: [Clockwize/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and [cdecl; C Gibberish<->English](http://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple: The variable `ptr` have not been declared. And no, `(int *) ptr[N];` is *not* a declaration, it's a typecast of an array subscript expression.

If you want an array of pointers, you should do

```
int *ptr[N];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is casting **N**th element of the array `ptr` to an integer pointer.

The error itself points to that `ptr` is never declared. You forgot or deleted my misstake a line like this:

```
int *ptr[123];
```

about the `N` it seems to be a constand which is normally defined e.g. like this:

```
#define N 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this

```
typedefine int* INT_PTR;
INT_PTR ptr[N];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler will cast ptr[N] to type (int *), just like

```
    int a;
    double b;
    b = (double)a;
```

so the (int *)ptr[N] dosen's have left value, and u never declare ptr before.
then gcc compiler will tell u ptr undeclared.